# download a file using Java, no api, strange error

Tags: java, web-scraping

I am trying to download a file from [this](http://www.anaptyxi.gov.gr/Analytika.aspx?mod=3&act=search&dim=01_36_514;) site, by clicking on the Excel icon. By right clicking on the icon I got the link which I pasted to my java program as such:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    BufferedReader br;
    String thisLine="";
    String file="";
    try {
      // connect and download the file
      ReadableByteChannel rbc;
      file="test.xls";
      URL website = new URL("http://www.anaptyxi.gov.gr/DesktopModules" +
                "/AVMap.ErgaReports_v2/SearchHandler.ashx?lang=el-GR" +
                "&pageMode=3&searchValue=&searchField=&dateFrom=&dateTo=" +
                "&perioxesMode=2&selectedPerioxes[]=01_36_514&ergaType[]=1" +
                "&ergaType[]=2&ergaType[]=3&enisx=&kad=&company=&includePollaplhs=1" +
                "&export=xls");
      rbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());

      FileOutputStream xls = new FileOutputStream(file);  
      xls.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);             
      xls.close();               
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }   
}
```

This creates an Excel file, but it only contains the string:

> Error executing the request. Try limiting your criteria.
>   Any ideas?

Comment: are you really breaking lines in your url string like you posted?

Comment: no, i posted it that way to be easier to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how it should look like if using java 8.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // connect and download the file
            URL website = new URL("http://www.anaptyxi.gov.gr/DesktopModules" +
                    "/AVMap.ErgaReports_v2/SearchHandler.ashx?lang=el-GR" +
                    "&pageMode=3&searchValue=&searchField=&dateFrom=&dateTo=" +
                    "&perioxesMode=2&selectedPerioxes[]=01_36_514&ergaType[]=1" +
                    "&ergaType[]=2&ergaType[]=3&enisx=&kad=&company=&includePollaplhs=1" +
                    "&export=xls");
            URLConnection con = website.openConnection();
            con.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
            con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36");

            Files.copy(con.getInputStream(), FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("test.html"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The site is probably checking the `User-Agent` header and not responding because you're using java.

This should fix it:

```
   public static void main(String[] args){

   BufferedReader br;
   String thisLine="";
   String file="";
   try {
       //   connect and download the file
      ReadableByteChannel rbc;
      file="test.xls";
      // connect and download the file
      URL website = new URL("http://www.anaptyxi.gov.gr/DesktopModules" +
                        "/AVMap.ErgaReports_v2/SearchHandler.ashx?lang=el-GR" +
                        "&pageMode=3&searchValue=&searchField=&dateFrom=&dateTo=" +
                        "&perioxesMode=2&selectedPerioxes[]=01_36_514&ergaType[]=1" +
                        "&ergaType[]=2&ergaType[]=3&enisx=&kad=&company=&includePollaplhs=1" +
                        "&export=xls");

      // Adding request headers to mimic the browser
      URLConnection con = website.openConnection();
      con.addRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
      con.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.90 Safari/537.36");
      rbc = Channels.newChannel(con.getInputStream());  // !!!


      FileOutputStream xls = new FileOutputStream(file);  
      xls.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);             
      xls.close();               
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Files.copy(con.getInputStream(), FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("test.txt")); gives me an error "The method getPath(String, String[]) in the type FileSystem is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: We are probably using different versions of the jdk. I'm using 1.8.0
Just focus on using the URL connection and adding the User-Agent request property.

Comment: I have the same version under Linux (Oracle Java not OpenJava). will look into it again.

Comment: I use this, but still get the same error on the filerbc = Channels.newChannel(website.openStream());
        FileOutputStream xls = new FileOutputStream("test3.txt");    
        xls.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);             
        xls.close();

Comment: you're focusing on the wrong thing. I've reverted my answer to look like your previous code. add done only the modification you're missing:  the use of URLConnection instead of a direct openStream()

Comment: since you mention that this is not an actual xls file, but an html table "wrapped" to xls, i have been trying to parse that html to java and get the data as csv. have some issues as told here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29905581/parse-an-html-table-from-internet-to-java-jsoup.

Comment: ok, I am not sure what happened here, Copying your updated code did the trick. I got the xls file as expected, only that it actually is an html table. if i open it on an editor i get html code. so my other post still stands since i have to read this file to csv. thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with your URL.  Usually when making an HTTP-type request, you need to check the response code, if it's not 200 something bad happened.  Besides a possible bad response code, looks like the service is returning an error also in the body instead of the expected data, perhaps that the query requested is going to return too much data, hence the "try limiting the criteria."

Read up on SLA defined with the service you're calling, it'll likely say something about how much data can be returned in any one call